# Agregar clase con php

Tags: php, html, class

tengo un enlace.

```
<a href="contacto.php?id='uno'" class="uno">contacto</a>
```

Quiero saber si puedo agregarle con php una clase más a ese enlace por ejemplo.

```
<a href="contacto.php" class="uno active">contacto</a>
```

Cómo lo puedo hacer ayúdenme!

Comment: ¿Quieres que al darle clic al enlace se agregue la clase? No me quedó muy claro tu pregunta

Comment: Ya por ejemplo dando click al enlace contacto se le agrega la clase active! se puede?

Comment: Sí, pero no con php. PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta del lado del servidor, lo que tú quieres hacer se puede con javascript y es muy fácil, ya te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: Te explico yo estoy haciendo un menu general para todas las paginas que tengo...y estoy usando el include para agregar el menu a todas las páginas...Como hago para que se agregué una clase a este enlace para tenerlo activo cuando este en la página.

Comment: Con javascript ya se como se hace lo quiero hacer con php! :(

Comment: prueba con `if ($estoyEnLaPaginaDelLink) : echo "active"; endif;`

Comment: Es una cuestión de dónde se ejecuta y qué lenguaje se utiliza en cada caso. Es un fallo en la lógica pensar en hacer esto desde PHP, ya que este lenguaje se ejecuta del lado del servidor. En PHP todo el procesamiento se hace una sola vez y para interactuar es necesario recargar el navegador. Para hacerlo deberías checkear la página en la que se encuentra el usuario y hacer que en base a eso agregue o no la clase «active», mediante un if.

Comment: se podría dar un ejemplo mas completo si agregas el código del menu y una de las paginas que lo incluyen

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el código de tu menú? Así sería más fácil ayudarte, y además agrega los detalles que has comentado.

Comment: La verdad no sabía cual marcar, ya que aquel es la que está mejor explicada y tiene la respuesta que el usuario quería, si se debe cerrar una pregunta creo que debería ser esta.

Answer (score 1):

Con PHP sé que no puedes, pero puedes intercalar código JavaScript y PHP para poder añadir la clase, me explico: Cuando vayas a redirigirte al archivo PHP puedes imprimir un código JS para que te agregue la clase:

```
<a href="contacto.php?id=uno" id="contacto" class="uno">contacto</a> <!-- Le agrego un Id para identificarlo con JS -->
```

Ahora imprimes este código con PHP:

```
<script>
   var contacto = document.getElementById("contacto");
   contacto.className += " active";
</script>
```

O puedes hacerlo por medio de JQuery:

```
<script>
   $('#contacto').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Es de recordarte que cuando imprimes con ´echo()´ Código de cualquier tipo, este lo toma cómo código real del documento.

Espero te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Que sentido tiene imprimir código javascript para añadir una clase, cuando se puede imprimir directamente el enlace activado?

Comment: Por si se quiere añadir esta clase en el mismo archivo, no mandando a otro, y así se ahorra el poner un if() y se hace más legible el código

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo, una de ellas puede ser así:

Imaginamos que la url es www.midominio.es/contacto

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$newClass = '';
if(preg_match('/^\/contacto/', $uri)){
    $newClass = ' active';
} ?>
```

Impresión entre el html

```
<a href="contacto.php" class="uno<?php echo $newClass; ?>">contacto</a>
```

Impresión dentro de PHP

```
<?php
//...
echo "<a href=\"contacto.php\" class=\"uno$newClass\">contacto</a>";
//...
?>
```

O esta otra:

```
<?php
//...
printf("<a href=\"contacto.php\" class=\"uno%s\">contacto</a>", $newClass);
//...
?>
```

Este sería el enlace que devuelve cualquiera de ellas:

```
<a href="contacto.php" class="uno active">contacto</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes hacerlo con PHP desde el navegador, pero si con un simple script de Jquery utilizando toggleClass o addClass de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".uno").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```